# React native navigation.goBack()

Tags: react-native

I have simple navigation in React Native project, it is using drawer.

I have menu with 4-5 pages only, and they are most of the time just one page navigation.

On home page I have menu and I navigate: navigation.navigate()... that is working fine, but when I want to come back I have "back" link with navigation.goBack()... goBack is returning to cached page (most of the time home page).

So for example inside header I have counter for un-read messages, then when I navigate to inbox with Navigation.navigate() I mark all messages as "read".

After clicking 'back' I still see counter on home page as it is cached, but if I navigate afterwards with navigation.navigate... it is reset, but again when coming back with navigation.goBack()... cached.

Is there any way to prevent this.

Thanks!

Thanks to Ahmad Abou Saleh... I slightly changed code as I am on navigation 5:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            //code goes here......
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this listener on home page to be triggered every time you access home page

```
//in componentDidMount() 
this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
'willFocus',
() => {
    //add your code here 
} 
);
//in componentWillUnmount() 
this.willFocusSubscription.remove(); //remove listener when page unmounted
```

Comment: Thanks! Inside componentDidMount I had just call to a function that is fetching data from DB. So when I added your code and I replaced ‘ //your code here’ with ‘this.getMessages()’. Now getMessages is not triggered. Do you have idea what I am doing wrong? Ps. I am not getting errors, just no data at all.

Comment: since I am using navigation 5... this code is slightly different... I'll edit my own question.. so if anybody need it can use it. Thanks for assistance, you give me idea what needs to be done!

Comment: no problem, don't forget to remove listener on componentWillUnmount(), so that your function don't be triggered when page is inactive

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Actually I didn’t put it... as I saw in the docs somewhere (don’t take my word for it) that using focus in Navigation 5 it is not needed any more. But I’ll look into it since you mentioned it... thanks again